# What is the correct url to access an file via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, thymeleaf

**To contextualize:**

There is a remote directory, `clearing-dit\logs`, which has a series of logs (`portal.log`, `test.log`, `...`). This directory is mapped to an HTML page, where all your `.log's` are displayed. Once one of them is clicked, its respective content is displayed.

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sv2g.png)

Currently, I'm using thymeleaf to show the content:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:include="layout :: page">
                ...
   <div ...>
    <p th: utext = "$ {log.content}"> Log content </ p>
  </div>
```

The problem is that this content is displayed in a static way, and I need it to be continue shown as the file is getting updates. I went searching and saw that I can/need to do it through an AJAX, but the concept of AJAX is quite vague to me.

Currently, I'm trying to do it in a very simple way:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/log",
    type : "post",
    success : function(data) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

And (to set the log content):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String logContent(@Valid Log log, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model) {
    if (log.getInitLine() == 0 && log.getFinalLine() == 0) {
        try {
            fileNumberLines(log);
            log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
    }

    model.put("path", logsDir);
    model.put("log", log);
    model.put("currentPage", "logs");
    model.put("root", root);

    return "log";
}
```

But instead of the contents of the file, I'm getting the page itself.

[Return AJAX call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJbPV.png)

What makes sense, since I'm passing the url of the page itself. So, **my question is:** How do I access log content through the url? What is the correct url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not return the name of the view from the Controller method if you are using it for AJAX. You need to return data (an Object) from the method. You will need the data to be converted to JSON (which can be used in Javascript) so you need to mark the method with `@ResponseBody`. You will also need [`jackson-databind`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) on the classpath (`com.fasterxml.jackson.core jackson-databind`) for the JSON conversion.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String logContent(@Valid Log log, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model) {
    if (log.getInitLine() == 0 && log.getFinalLine() == 0) {
        try {
            fileNumberLines(log);
            log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
    }

    model.put("path", logsDir);
    model.put("log", log);
    model.put("currentPage", "logs");
    model.put("root", root);

    return log;//return an Object containing data (or your own Value Object)
}
```

Comment: Got it! But in doing so I keep "over use" this url and "lose" my view, right? Is there a way to load the view and then load the object inside the view?

Comment: @DavidCaina You should have different Controller methods (or different Controllers) for returning view names and AJAX calls. They can not use the same Controller method.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the file itself, because you're returning a view name from the method. So, Spring doesn't know if you're asking it to return only the data. One way to get this done is to use `@ResponseBody` annotation.

This allows you to send any arbitrary data to the client. So, you may want to change your method to something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String logContent(@Valid Log log, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model) {
    // Code truncated for brevity

    return log;
}
```

What we're doing here is instructing Spring to return the contents of `log` object directly to the client, instead of rendering a view. Hope this helps.